How to send a google calendar notification with authorization?
I'm using the following nodejs API https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert#node.js to send google calendar notifications.
How can I send a notification to be added to the user's calendar without them having to go through the google authorization process?
I noticed that the google API requires an auth.
